# Making Ubuntu Server get IPv4 address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipv4, yaml

I am having an issue when I go to use sudo netplan apply. I get an error. its going to be where the 1st x in addresses is x.x.x.x/x
it gives me an expected sequence error.
it is ubuntu 18.04
Any advice would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Wild guess -  don't the IP addresses/ranges need to be enclosed in square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

"Expected sequence" means the field must be a *list,* not a single value. Even if it's just a single item, it *still* has to be formatted like a list – the same way as you currently have the nameserver addresses.

In YAML there are two ways to write a list (i.e. a sequence):

1. One item per line:

   ```
   addresses:
   - x.x.x.x/23
   - y.y.y.y/23
   ```
2. JSON-style:

   ```
   addresses: [x.x.x.x/23, y.y.y.y/23]
   ```

<sub>(Given it's YAML, there are probably five more ways to write a list, but who cares about those.)</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I was able to finally to make it work.